# Python decryption with lists

Tags: python, list, encryption

I'm stuck with a decryption problem I'm having.  I have a really basic cipher that is only the alphabet and is offset by 1 letter, like this:

```
A    B
B    C
C    D
D    E
to z  to A
```

the right column is the letters I'm given, and I need to turn them to the letters on the left.

I'm reading this from a file, and saving each column into a list like this

```
#!/usr/bin/python

key = "key.txt"
encrypted = "encrypted.txt"
decrypted = "decrypted.txt"

encryptedList = []
decryptedList = []

with open(key, "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        currentLine = line.split()

        currentDecrypted = currentLine[0]
        currentEncrypted = currentLine[1]

        decryptedList.append(currentEncrypted)
        encryptedList.append(currentDecrypted)

file.close()

counter = 0
with open(encrypted, "r") as file:
for line in file:
    currentLine = line
    for letter in currentLine:
        currentLetter = letter
        for item in encryptedList:
            if(item == currentLetter):
            ####here's where the problem starts####
            ####I've tried just printing counter, and I get mostly go    
                printencryptedList[counter-1]
                counter = 0
                break
            counter += 1
```

what I'm trying to decrypt is a text file that looks like this

```
FMMP
NZ OBNF JT KSMBB
KPIO TVDLT BQQ
GWWWWWWBMT PG DJJJJJH
```

I get the correct count numbers for FMMP, (5, 12, 12, 15) with counter -1, but then i get 39, 25,40 and so on.  Any help would be greatly appreciated, and let me know if you need more info.

I also welcome ideas on better/easier ways to do this, but I would also like a solution similar to this, so I can figure out what's going on here.  Thanks

Alright, thanks for all the answers and info.  I'm posting what I finally did and it works.  I'm sure it's not as pythonic as it should be, but I implemented a few things that people mentioned.  Thanks for the info.

```
import string

key = "key.txt"
encrypted = ""encrypted.txt"
decrypted = "decrypted.txt


encryptedString = ""
decryptedString = ""

keyDict = {}

with open(key, "r") as file:
    for line in file:
    currentLine = line.split()

    currentDecrypted = currentLine[0]
    currentEncrypted = currentLine[1]

    keyDict[currentDecrypted] = currentEncrypted


with open(encrypted, "r") as file:
    for line in file:
    currentLine = line
        for letter in currentLine:
        currentLetter = letter
        encryptedString += letter
            for key in keyDict:
            if(keyDict[key] == letter):
                decryptedString += key
                break
            elif(letter == " "):
                decryptedString += " "
                break
            elif(letter == "\n"):
                decryptedString += "\n"
                break




with open(decrypted, "a") as file:
    file.write(decryptedString)
```

Comment: Have a look at Python's dictionaries (instead of your two parallel lists).

Comment: Interesting idea, thanks.  I've used dictionaries before, and at first I didn't use a dictionary because I thought not being able to order them would matter, but I guess it actually won't.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I removed the post that you said "No" to right after I posted it because I realized my mistake.  Thanks

Comment: maybe is homework, maybe is not, but if you want to use this in a real project, dont! Use PyCrypto! Anyways, you dont need "file.close" if you're using "with" statement.

Comment: Thanks, habit to put the file.close.

Comment: The decrypted output is funny.

Comment: I think it's great that nobody post the result here - so that anybody coming along must try it on his own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You definitely should use dictionaries. Together with Pythons `map()`, your task is really simple:

```
import string

secret = """FMMP
NZ OBNF JT KPTIVB
KPIO TVDLT BTT
GVOEBNFOUBMT PG DPNQVUJOH"""

characters = list(string.uppercase)
cipher = dict(zip(characters[1:]+[characters[0]], characters))

decrypted = "".join(map(lambda x: cipher.get(x,x), secret))

print decrypted
```

I won't post the result of the decryption here as I don't have a "Parental Advisory"-sticker atm. ;-) Just try it!

Of course there are helper functions in the `string`-module, but OP wants to learn python, not implement a "bullet-proof" cryptographic system.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know what was on there was bad haha, I didn't even check it by hand first before I posted it.  That's my bad.  I changed it.

Comment: Being a beginner in python, this is a lot to learn in one step :)  map is new to me, and so is lambda.  Thanks for this, now I've got lots to read through.

Comment: That was my intent. Python has many nice programming patterns from many different paradigms. These two concepts are functional, and I love it.

Comment: `dic.get(x,x)` is equivalent to `x if cipher.get(x) is None else cipher[x]`.

Comment: how does this handle the spaces?  I know it does, and it works perfectly, but I'm having trouble seeing how it handles them here.

Comment: It ignores all values not found in cipher, leaving them as they were.

Comment: `dict(izip_longest(up,up[1:],fillvalue="Z"))` can also be used here, where `up=string.uppercase[::-1]`

Comment: Another new concept for the OP - iterators! Definitely have a look at that. It's in the module `itertools`

Answer (score 5):

[str.translate](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) is best suited for [Caesar cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher) type encryption which seems to be what you are trying to do

You first need to create a translation table through [string.maketrans](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.maketrans)

The Upper Case alpha characters can be fetched from [string.ascii_uppercase](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.ascii_uppercase)

To Rotate the Alpha Characters you can simply do `ascii_uppercase[1:] + ascii_uppercase[0]`

Now it's a cakewalk from here

```
>>> secret = """FMMP
NZ OBNF JT KPTIVB
KPIO TVDLT BTT
GVOEBNFOUBMT PG DPNQVUJOH"""
>>> from string import ascii_uppercase as UPPER, maketrans
>>> print secret.translate(maketrans(UPPER[1:] + UPPER[0], UPPER))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary and a converter function instead:

```
my_crypt = {
    "a":"b",
    "b":"c",
    "c":"d"
    ...
}

def crypt_str(in_str, crypt_dict):
    out_str = ""
    for char in in_str:
        if char in crypt_dict:
            out_str += crypt_dict[char]
        else:
            out_str += char
    return out_str

>>> print(crypt_str("hello!", my_crypt))
ifmmp!
```

The advantage over other methods provided here: If you ever want to change the way it converts, for example turn characters into numbers - it works all the same.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a really basic cipher that is only the alphabet and is offset by 1 letter.

Is this true? The code you show supports arbitrary substitution. If that's not needed, then:

```
encstr = 'FMMP NZ OBNF JT KPTIVB KPIO TVDLT BTT GVOEBNFOUBMT PG DPNQVUJOH'
decstr = ''.join([(chr(ord(ech)-1) if 'A' <= ech <= 'Z' else ech) for ech in encstr])
```

### EDIT

The original example expects cleartext 'Z' to wrap to 'A' rather than bump to '[' (in ASCII). To properly handle this:

```
''.join([(chr(ord('A')+(ord(ech)-ord('A')-1)%26 ) if 'A' <= ech <= 'Z' else ech) for ech in encstr])
```

So this is getting a little ugly. `translate` is starting to look good at this point. [See @Abhijit's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14453947/python-decryption-with-lists/14454192#14454192).

Comment: Your code seems to be unchecked. It treats the "space" just like any char and therefore messes it up. You also have a typo: `for ech in enc]`. I'll fix this.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I tested a couple versions locally but pasted the wrong line which also fixes the space issue, which I'm now editing. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Python has built in functions for these kinds of simple ciphers, so there is no need to use dictionaries:

[string.translate](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/string.html#string.translate)

[string.maketrans](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/string.html#string.maketrans)

Example:

```
>>> s='''FMMP
NZ OBNF JT KSMBB
KPIO TVDLT BQQ
GWWWWWWBMT PG DJJJJJH'''
>>> import string
>>> tr = string.maketrans(string.uppercase[1:]+'A', string.uppercase)
>>> print string.translate(s,tr)
```